# How did they make "Get Windows 10" icon to have "Show icon and notifications" visibility by default?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-shell, windows-explorer

I'm curious how did this thing:

[image]

happen to become "Show icon and notifications" by default?

[image]

My impression was that [Shell_NotifyIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159(v=vs.85).aspx) didn't allow to control that.

So did anyone have a chance to reverse-engineer it to see how they did it?

Comment: It's like the consent decree never happened isn't it...

Comment: Didn't that come as part of a system update? They could have just forced the behavior with the update.

Comment: @Juhana: Yes, it was indeed part of a system update.  But IIRC, the default behavior for a newly discovered icon is to display it, and then the user can decide what to do with it.

Comment: I guess they are allowed to break the rules......

Comment: Yeah, my point is that Microsoft isn't bound by the same rules as others because they can change whatever they want in an update.

Comment: @Juhana: Yes, this is an update but in this case they have to play by their own rules. Let me explain. The visibility settings for icons on the system tray reside internally in `explorer.exe`. It is obviously otherwise stored in Registry. So when `explorer.exe` starts up at a user logon, it reads those visibility settings from the Registry. It then saves them when it exits, at user logoff. It doesn't save those in the meantime. (You can check that by killing its process and see that all your changes to tray icons visibility will be lost.)

Comment: Since this Windows 10 icon doesn't come from the `explorer.exe` itself (as a possible part of an update) but actually resides in its own user-mode process `gwx.exe`, by running as any other user process, it must be able to communicate with `explorer.exe` and have it show that icon after `explorer.exe` has loaded up. So, in other words, this is not a modification to `explorer.exe` itself that does this.

Comment: I tried looking into `gwx.exe` with Dependency Walker to see if it's calling any particular API that I was not aware of, but I couldn't find any. So my guess is that there must be some undocumented COM interface that they're using to change an icon's visibility. Since I don't have much experience with COM, I'm curious if there's something like Dependency Walker for COM for a specific process?

Answer (score 0):

They are calling Shell_NotifyIcon with a undocumented flag. I'm being vague on purpose because I don't want every application with a notify icon to start doing this.

I believe it is possible to do this as far back as Win XP (when the hidden icons feature was added).

Comment: *I think I have an untested and unconfirmed idea of what might be happening, but I'm not going to share it with anyone* is not an answer. (It wouldn't even make a useful comment to the original question.)

Comment: Because I'm not sure if it is a good idea to post the full details. What do think? Are you just curious or do you want your applications to do the same thing?

Comment: @KenWhite I have done it myself, it is not an unconfirmed idea.

Comment: I don't need my applications to do any such thing. But posting a *I have the information but won't share it* answer isn't an answer. You're not new here; you know what answers should be and what they should not. If you have no answer to provide, then don't post an answer.

Comment: @KenWhite I have actually had answers downvoted and edited because I posted information on how to bypass some Group Policy thing. For most people it should be enough just to know that it is just a simple flag, there is no need to hunt for COM interfaces. You only need the value of the flag if you intent to actually use it in your own code...